# how to get CallId in CSipSimple in Android

Tags: android, csip-simple

I am using CSipSimple for adding a new feature which is transfer call . For this feature I need the callID of call .

I am seeing that when I call ,the following function is called .

```
public void placeCallWithOption(Bundle b) {
        if (service == null) {
            return;
        }
        String toCall = "";
        Long accountToUse = SipProfile.INVALID_ID;
        // Find account to use
        SipProfile acc = accountChooserButton.getSelectedAccount();
        if(acc == null) {
            return;
        }

        accountToUse = acc.id;
        // Find number to dial
        toCall = digits.getText().toString();
        if(isDigit) {
            toCall = PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators(toCall);
        }

        if(accountChooserFilterItem != null && accountChooserFilterItem.isChecked()) {
            toCall = rewriteNumber(toCall);
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(toCall)) {
            return;
        }

        // Well we have now the fields, clear theses fields
        digits.getText().clear();

        // -- MAKE THE CALL --//
        if (accountToUse >= 0) {
            // It is a SIP account, try to call service for that
            try {
                service.makeCallWithOptions(toCall, accountToUse.intValue(), b);
              //  service.xfer(callId,"01628105601");
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                Log.e(THIS_FILE, "Service can't be called to make the call");
            }
        } else if (accountToUse != SipProfile.INVALID_ID) {
            // It's an external account, find correct external account
            CallHandlerPlugin ch = new CallHandlerPlugin(getActivity());
            ch.loadFrom(accountToUse, toCall, new OnLoadListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoad(CallHandlerPlugin ch) {
                    placePluginCall(ch);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

But from this , I can't get callId of the call. How can I get callId of each call ? Any advice is of great help .

Answer (score 0):

Using SipCallSession to fetch a call id

```
SipCallSession callInfo = new SipCallSession();
callinfo.getCallid();
```